# How can I receive message from Asp.Net WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a little problem. I need to write client-server application that do some things.

Client side: console application that waiting messages from web site, and answer on this messages.

Server side: web application on that another client, do something and after this controller create message and send this to client side.

For server side I want to use asp.net mvc with webapi and for client side .net console application. But I don't understand how I can receive message from site like push in console.

To resolve my problem I have one idea: every 5 seconds from client ask server. But I think that is not right. Please give me right solution for this.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, if I understand your problem, you need to send any message from web api to the console app, if this, I can give you to options: 1) SignalR that is designed to real time applications http://www.asp.net/signalr and 2) WebHooks that has a similar model to signalr: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/09/04/introducing-microsoft-asp-net-webhooks-preview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would build a separate thread, this thread's only purpose would be to listen continuously (without jamming the main process) to see if there is something to catch, so as soon as there is something, handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd look at duplexes. They allow for servers to send messages to the client.

Here is the documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a bare bones example I wrote for it a couple years ago:
https://github.com/Aelphaeis/MyWcfDuplexPipeExample/blob/master/MyWcfDuplexExample.Client/Program.cs

There are some challenges using duplexes in production environments so I suggest you read into that.